# Autoload with psr-4 my own classes in a monorepo

Tags: php, wordpress, autoload, psr-4

I'm writing a WordPress plugin within a monorepo architecture, this is my directory structure:

```bash
packages/
  ├── plugin
  └── dependencie-1
```

In `dependencie-1` I have a psr-4 autoload configured in composer.json:

```json
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Mdorim\\": "src/php/"
    }
}
```

And in `plugin` my composer.json is as follow:

```json
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "LCDR\\": "./src/php",
        "LCDR\\Tests\\": "./tests/Pest"
    }
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "../mdorim"
    }
],
"require": {
    "monorepo/mdorim": "@dev"
},
```

At the main file of `plugin` I'm requiring the autoloader from vendor

```php
require '../vendor/autoload.php'
```

While I can access all the classes from `plugin` with the autoloader configured, I can't use the classes from `dependencie-1` and I keep getting this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "Mdorim\Core" not found in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/elucidario-art/lcdr.php:52
```

Obviously the classes from dependencies are not at the main path of `plugin` but in its `vendor` directory. The psr-4 should not resolve this? Am I missing something?

### update

It's probably something with the docker not resolving the symlinked directory, because it's working properly in a phpunit configured test.
But nothing happend if I use symlink option false at repositories configuration for dependencie-1 at composer.json:

```json
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "../mdorim",
        "options": {
            "symlink": false
        }
    }
],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved the problem with symlink option marked as false, but I had to delete `composer.lock` and run `composer install` again.